# Can permanent delete the GitHub deleted Repository list?

Tags: github

If I want to clean my GitHub deleted Repository history what should I do?

Here is the list I want to clear out:

[image: deleted repositories]

Comment: Why did you not edit your question before submitting it so that the image link is not in the middle of a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [About repository restoration](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/restoring-a-deleted-repository#about-repository-restoration)

> A deleted repository can be restored within 90 days, unless the repository was part of a fork network that is not currently empty.

So that list is likely to be cleared out after 90 days for a given repository.
If that is too long, you would need to contact [GitHub support](https://support.github.com/request?tags=docs-generic).

Comment: ok i will check that